# Can we get only value of _source field using ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Consider the below mapping:

```
PUT imagetest
{
   "mappings": {
      "imageMap": {
         "properties": {
            "image": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "no"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Using below query

```
GET imagetest/imageMap/11601_100_44/_source
```

I am getting this

```
{
   "image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkS...."
}
```

I want to write a query that will give me below result

```
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkS...."
```

Comment: The closest you can get to that is by adding the `?format=yaml` to your URL

Comment: @Val Actually i want to use query as simple url that return base64string. So that browser can easily consume/cache it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The browser will cache the response based on the URL and the usual HTTP caching headers, not based on the response itself, whatever the format of the response is. Feel free to explain your use case in more details.

Comment: @Val I want to save images in ES and retrieve them using simple url, So that browser can cache images. (caching is preferred but can be omitted).

Comment: Again, the browser doesn't care about the format of your response and will cache any response based on the URL and the HTTP headers. So what you're asking is a non-issue in my opinion... Just make sure to use the proper [HTTP caching headers](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) in your GET call and you're good to go

Comment: @Val Thank you, i got answer for my one question about caching, But still struggling with the main question. Can ElasticSearch has a way to return only value of a _source -> field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108905/discussion-between-irshad-ali-and-val).